# logstash configuration to add / mutate three attributes to a list

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have three attributes coming in from a grok{ } filter, I am trying to add them in a list some thing like this :

```
parentAttrName:[
     iEDate : iEDateValue,
     iLNum : iLNumValue,
     iQ : iQValue
]
```

I have used **add_tag => ["%{ilmdExpirationDate}","%{iLNumValue}","%{iQValue}"]** in grok but it is adding only value of these attributes in a list named **tags**.

like this :

```
"tags": [
           "2017-07-02",
           "OT-365",
           "365",
           "2016-10-10T10:14:35.000000010"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this `mutate` filter:

```
filter {
   mutate {
      add_field => {
          "[parentAttrName][iEDate]" => "%{ilmdExpirationDate}"
          "[parentAttrName][iLNum]" => "%{iLNumValue}"
          "[parentAttrName][iQ]" => "%{iQValue}"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove some filed from output :

Comment: mutate {
 remove_field =>["%{ilmd}","%{event_ext_raw}"]
    }

Comment: I suggest you create a new question since this is a different problem.

Comment: Correct Syntex : mutate { remove_field =>["ilmd","event_ext_raw"] }

Comment: Glad you figured it out. The new question was just so that people with the same issue as yours can find the solution more easily